# Python Dask - Check if there are duplicates

Tags: python, dask

Although there are many answered questions explaining how to get or drop duplicates from a dask DataFrame, I am interested in know if there are duplicates only. That means, I do not need a list of unique or duplicated values.

The `pandas.DataFrame.duplicated` is not available on dask (https://github.com/dask/dask/issues/1854), hence my current approach is as follows for finding out if there are duplicates in the pairs defined by col1 and col2 and a given dask DataFrame `dd`:

```
dd_total_count = dd.shape[0].compute()
dd_uniques_count = dd.drop_duplicates(subset=["col1", "col2"]).shape[0].compute()

duplicates_contained = (dd_total_count == dd_uniques_count)
```

For `dd` containing about 100GB data, this takes *very long* time. What other way of checking if there are duplicates in `dd` could be faster? If there is no better way than the one above, what other techniques could I apply to speed up the code above? Is sorting by col1 and col2 in advance useful?

In case it might be important, col1 contains datetime data and col2 string data.